# using jquery mobile with java, is it possible?

Tags: java, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to know how to use the jquery mobile with java coding in the same application, so I can merge some features not available in the jquery platform to make some advanced android application.

appreciate your responses.

Comment: What features do you want to use?

Comment: nevermind about the features. I just want an app that is developed using jquery mobile and java at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First don't listen personne3000, apparently he never touched Phonegap.

It can be done with jQuery Mobile if you use it with Phonegap. Phonegap, while working as a wrapper for HTML5/JS/CSS will give you access to native JAVA code (Android only of course). Phonegap will give you access to the wide range of mobile phone compatibilities ranging from camera, sound record up to creating native tab bar for your app.

[Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html) you will find a "iOS Getting started" tutorial for Phonegap/Cordova and [here's](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) an Android tutorial.

[Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/index.html) you can find basic Phonegap/Cordova API reference and this is just a basic list, much more can be found in 3rd party plugin list [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

In case you can't find functionality you need you can create your own plugin and [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html) you will find a Phonegap plugin tutorial for Android platform. In case you are going to use an older version of Phonegap (pre Cordova) [here](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)'s an older plugin creation tutorial.

Comment: one more question please, this will let me have everything in java and jquery mobil. isn't it?

Comment: Plugins serve as bridge between java script and java, you are limited only by your imagination. If you have enough time you could create an appcelerator titanium look alike app that will use java script to create a native android app.

Comment: then i can't use some java codes like Toast and database things!!

Comment: Phonegap plugin has two parts, one is javascript part and other one is the java part. If your frameworks can run in normal Android application then they will run in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly use jQuery mobile to develop your app. However, you can :

- Develop an Android application using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or Cordova in HTML5/Javascript, and use jQuery mobile, but you won't have access to Java
- Use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)s to display webpages with Javascript included. You might want to look at the addJavascriptInterface method.

Javascript and Java can't be mixed just like that in an application : they work very differently.